# How remove the attribute from anguler.js array?

Tags: angularjs

I am having an anguler.js array like below,

```
"serviceLevels": [
        {
            "cutOffTime": "11:00",
            "dgs": [
                {
                    "active": "Y",
                    "cutoffTime": null,
                    "dgId": "DG100",
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "active": "Y",
                            "effEndDt": "2015-05-15T19:37:00+0000",
                            "effStDt": "2015-05-15T19:37:00+0000",
                            "locId": "BBY_1000",
                            "rank": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "rank": "1"
                },
                {
                    "active": "Y",
                    "cutoffTime": null,
                    "dgId": "DG8113",
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "active": "Y",
                            "effEndDt": "2015-08-11T09:46:00+0000",
                            "effStDt": "2015-08-11T09:46:00+0000",
                            "locId": "BBY_1064",
                            "rank": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "rank": "1"
                }
            ],
            "overrideCutOffTime": "",
            "serviceLevel": "SAME_DAY"
        }
    ]
```

From the above array I need to remove cutoffTime attribute from dgs array.I'm trying like this but its taking null value, can anyone help me on this?.

```
var svcs = eval($scope.rgnSvcLevels);
                    for (var j = 0; j < svcs.length; j++) {
                     var dgs =  eval(svcs[j].dgs)
                      if (dgs != null) {
                           for (var k = 0; k < dgs.length; k++) {
                                dgs[k].cutoffTime=null
                           }
                       }
                    }
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: Do you want to remove cutoffTime  from the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
delete dgs[k].cutoffTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

For any Javascript basic operation always search first MDN. Here is official documentation for delete property from object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```
/*detele object property */
var svcs = eval($scope.rgnSvcLevels);
                for (var j = 0; j < svcs.length; j++) {
                 var dgs =  eval(svcs[j].dgs)
                  if (dgs != null) {
                       for (var k = 0; k < dgs.length; k++) {
                           delete dgs[k].cutoffTime;
                       }
                   }
                }
```